Is this an error in the documentation of TransparentBlt()?
Microsoft's documentation of the GDI function TransparentBlt() states:

The TransparentBlt function supports all formats of source bitmaps. However, for 32 bpp bitmaps, it just copies the alpha value over.

Is this an error?
The code below contradicts that documentation by demonstrating that TransparentBlt() zeroes out the Alpha channel value for the non-transparent pixel, and does not copy any channels of the source transparent pixel at all (as it shouldn't):
#include <windows.h>

void Test_TransparentBlt(void)
{
    BITMAPINFO bmi = { {sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 2, 1,1,32,BI_RGB,0,0,0,0,0} };
    PDWORD PixelsSrc;
    HBITMAP hBmpSrc = CreateDIBSection(0, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (PVOID*)&PixelsSrc, NULL, 0);
    PixelsSrc[0] = 0xEE555555; PixelsSrc[1] = 0xFFAAAAAA;

    PDWORD PixelsDst;
    HBITMAP hBmpDst = CreateDIBSection(0, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (PVOID*)&PixelsDst, NULL, 0);
    PixelsDst[0] = 0xCC222222; PixelsDst[1] = 0xDD333333;
    
    HDC hDCsrc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HDC hDCdst = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    SelectObject(hDCsrc, hBmpSrc);
    SelectObject(hDCdst, hBmpDst);
    
    printf("Src: %08X, %08X\n", PixelsSrc[0], PixelsSrc[1]);    
    printf("Dst: %08X, %08X\n", PixelsDst[0], PixelsDst[1]);
    TransparentBlt(hDCdst, 0, 0, 2, 1, hDCsrc, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0x00555555);
    printf("DST: %08X, %08X\n", PixelsDst[0], PixelsDst[1]);
}

The output is:
Src: EE555555, FFAAAAAA
Dst: CC222222, DD333333
DST: CC222222, 00AAAAAA

If the source Alpha value for the non-transparent pixel had been copied over, then the output would have been:
Src: EE555555, FFAAAAAA
Dst: CC222222, DD333333
DST: CC222222, FFAAAAAA

Note: the Alpha channel is encoded in the MSB of the pixel data (bigendian DWORD).
Does this function behave like that in all Windows versions ?

use AlphaBlend or GdiAlphaBlend instead TransparentBlt

@RbMm:  AlphaBlend() is useless to me because it cannot predicate the Alpha channel values on the RGB values.  Anyway, this question is only about the alleged documentation error.

Is this real code? Apparently the first two printf statements output the same data. And it doesn't look like C code.

You've been tinkering with the posted code for nearly an hour. Have you copy/pasted the actual code? Are you using a c++ compiler?

I'll be doing something similar but my solution uses another DIB section as a scratch buffer to which manually calculated alpha blended source and dest pixels are written, and then present to a window DC with StretchDIBits. Source and dest DCs are not necessary.

Is reinterpret_cast<PVOID*>(&PixelsDst) C code?

@WeatherVane: Compile with the /TP switch to get the C++ compiler features in C code. This is also reachable via the VisualStudio GUI in: Project Properties C/C++ / Advanced / Compile As .  Since that cast syntax was bothering you, I changed it to the old one: (PVOID*)&PixelsDst for you.

Seems like a documentation (or perhaps translation?) mistake. From the context I think what is meant is that the function "overwrites" the alpha value (e.g. with zero).

English is the native language for Microsoft's documentation, thus if any translation takes place it is from English - not into English.  Also, the phrase "copies over" is pretty unambiguous in that language. It is very distinct from "writes over" or "overwrites".

The person writing the documentation isn't necessarily a native English speaker. Regardless, the observed behavior doesn't match the documented behavior so one of them is incorrect.

Regardless of how it happened, it sounds like the answer to the OP's question is "yes".

I suggest you could post a feedback via the Feedback button in the Doc.
