Since when have the notifications registered by LdrRegisterDllNotification() started to act differently?
The Microsoft's documentation about the function LdrRegisterDllNotification() states that DLL load notifications registered by this function:

This notification occurs before dynamic linking takes place.

I wrote the following test program to test this assertion and I found out that in Windows 7 x64 these notifications act exactly like the documentation describes them, however in Windows 10 x64 they act very differently - namely, they occur after the DLL imports have been resolved and imported functions' entry points have been written to the Import Address Table ( IAT ), which is pointed to by the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress->FirstThunk.u1.Function
VOID CALLBACK NotificationFunction(_In_ ULONG NotificationReason, _In_ PLDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_DATA pNotificationData, _In_opt_ PVOID Context)
{
    if (NotificationReason == LDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_REASON_LOADED)
    {
        printf(" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n");
        printf("LOADED: %wZ @ %p\n\n", pNotificationData->Loaded.FullDllName, pNotificationData->Loaded.DllBase);
        if (!_wcsicmp((wchar_t*)Context, pNotificationData->Loaded.FullDllName->Buffer) || !_wcsicmp((wchar_t*)Context, pNotificationData->Loaded.BaseDllName->Buffer))
            PrintImports((PBYTE)pNotificationData->Loaded.DllBase);
    }
}


int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    HMODULE hMod1 = LoadLibraryEx(argv[1], NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES); 
    if (hMod1)
    {

        printf(" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n");
        printf("LOADED UNRESOLVED %ls @ %p\n\n", argv[1], hMod1);
        if (PrintImports((PBYTE)hMod1)) 
            printf("\nWARNING: Some functions have pre-bound entry points / addresses\n");

        FreeLibrary(hMod1);

        PVOID cookie;
        NTSTATUS nts = LdrRegisterDllNotification(0, &NotificationFunction, argv[1], &cookie);            

        HMODULE hMod2 = LoadLibrary(argv[1]);
        if (hMod2) {
           printf(" ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n");
           printf("LOADED RESOLVED %ls @ %p\n\n", argv[1], hMod2);
        }
       
        nts = LdrUnregisterDllNotification(&cookie);

        if (hMod2) {
            PrintImports((PBYTE)hMod2);
            FreeLibrary(hMod2);
        }    
    } else {
        printf("\nERROR: Loading library %ls\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

The full Visual Studio project with the entire source code is available at the following address: tinyurl.com/4RbMm123
In Windows 7 x64, this test program generates the following output:
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
LOADED UNRESOLVED x.dll @ 000007FEF6030000

API-MS-Win-Core-LibraryLoader-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls                  0000000000001230

API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll @ 00000000772E0000
    GetCurrentProcessId                        000000000000128C
    GetCurrentThreadId                         0000000000001276

API-MS-Win-Core-Profile-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    QueryPerformanceCounter                    00000000000012CC

API-MS-Win-Core-SysInfo-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime                    000000000000131A
    GetTickCount                               000000000000130A

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
LOADED: x.dll @ 000007FEF5FF0000

API-MS-Win-Core-LibraryLoader-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls                  0000000000001230

API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll @ 00000000772E0000
    GetCurrentProcessId                        000000000000128C
    GetCurrentThreadId                         0000000000001276

API-MS-Win-Core-Profile-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    QueryPerformanceCounter                    00000000000012CC

API-MS-Win-Core-SysInfo-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime                    000000000000131A
    GetTickCount                               000000000000130A

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
LOADED RESOLVED x.dll @ 000007FEF6030000

API-MS-Win-Core-LibraryLoader-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls                  0000000000001230 : 000007FEFD68B0B0

API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll @ 00000000772E0000
    GetCurrentProcessId                        000000000000128C : 00000000772F32C0
    GetCurrentThreadId                         0000000000001276 : 00000000772F1CA0

API-MS-Win-Core-Profile-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    QueryPerformanceCounter                    00000000000012CC : 0000000077553BE0

API-MS-Win-Core-SysInfo-L1-1-0.dll @ 000007FEFD680000
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime                    000000000000131A : 000007FEFD681760
    GetTickCount                               000000000000130A : 000007FEFD681120


However in Windows 10 x64, the same test program with the same x.dll generates the following output:
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
LOADED UNRESOLVED x.dll @ 00007FF9005C0000

API-MS-Win-Core-LibraryLoader-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls                  0000000000001230

API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF906BC0000
    GetCurrentProcessId                        000000000000128C
    GetCurrentThreadId                         0000000000001276

API-MS-Win-Core-Profile-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    QueryPerformanceCounter                    00000000000012CC

API-MS-Win-Core-SysInfo-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime                    000000000000131A
    GetTickCount                               000000000000130A

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
LOADED: x.dll @ 00007FF9005C0000

API-MS-Win-Core-LibraryLoader-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls                  0000000000001230 : 00007FF9052C6C70

API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF906BC0000
    GetCurrentProcessId                        000000000000128C : 00007FF906BE4BA0
    GetCurrentThreadId                         0000000000001276 : 00007FF906BD5860

API-MS-Win-Core-Profile-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    QueryPerformanceCounter                    00000000000012CC : 00007FF907B70160

API-MS-Win-Core-SysInfo-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime                    000000000000131A : 00007FF9052A4240
    GetTickCount                               000000000000130A : 00007FF9052A0F80

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
LOADED RESOLVED x.dll @ 00007FF9005C0000

API-MS-Win-Core-LibraryLoader-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls                  0000000000001230 : 00007FF9052C6C70

API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF906BC0000
    GetCurrentProcessId                        000000000000128C : 00007FF906BE4BA0
    GetCurrentThreadId                         0000000000001276 : 00007FF906BD5860

API-MS-Win-Core-Profile-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    QueryPerformanceCounter                    00000000000012CC : 00007FF907B70160

API-MS-Win-Core-SysInfo-L1-1-0.dll @ 00007FF905250000
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime                    000000000000131A : 00007FF9052A4240
    GetTickCount                               000000000000130A : 00007FF9052A0F80

As you can see, in Windows 10 x64 the entry points of the imported functions are resolved in the "LOADED:" and "LOADED RESOLVED" sections, however in Windows 7 x64 the imported functions are resolved only in the "LOADED RESOLVED" section (that's after the LoadLibrary() returns), which agrees with the most current documentation.
Q:  When exactly has this change happened ?  i.e. in what version, service pack, update...

in win 8.1 also this callback when was import already resolved. and at all - what is different for you ? in any case this was before dll entry point. so incorrect call any dll functions at this stage. so resolved import or not - for what this need ?

Simply, if you wite the address of your own private function into the IAT when inside this DLL load notifiction/callback, then in Win10 it will be called after the callback returns (instead of the original imported fn) but in Win7 your private function will NOT be called because the IAT will be overwritten after the callback returns. This is a major inconsistency.

Sounds like a good time to report a documentation bug to Microsoft.

@nneonneo:  It would not be the first time.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79091928/is-this-an-error-in-the-documentation-of-transparentblt

use LdrFindEntryForAddress. replace LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY::EntryPoint for self function. in it process your import, return LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY::EntryPoint to original value and if it not 0, call it

@RbMm: That suggestion is for Win7 only, isn't it ?  Anyway, this method involves first using LdrRegisterDllNotification() and then calling LdrFindEntryForAddress() inside the notification/callback to hook the DLL's entry point, which is called AFTER the imports are resolved even in Win7. Я правильно вас понял?

@RbMm: Are TLS Callouts executed AFTER the DLL's imports are resolved in all versions of Windows ?

@GeorgeRobinson Are TLS Callouts executed AFTER the imports are resolved in all versions of Windows - and how you think ? how possible call function from dll, if import yet not resolved ?

@RbMm: I am asking - not stating. Maybe it is possible if the TLS Callouts pointer is stored in the PEB and made to point to a function residing outside of the DLL and the NT Loader calls this function via this pointer.
